# Submit inheriting class from partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a base LogSearchModel class with the following properties:

```
public class LogSearchModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LogType {get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have two inheriting classes:

```
public class ActivityLogSearchModel : LogSearchModel
{
        public string Message { get; set; }            
}
public class ErrorLogSearchModel : LogSearchModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Razor view in place with editors for the properties of the base LogSearchModel class as follows:

```
@model LogSearchModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogType)
```

The logtype editor is actually a kendo dropdown which is restricted to the "Activity Log" and "Error Log" values. Based on the value of this dropdown, an Ajax call is made and an extra partial view with editors for the properties of the inheriting classes is displayed:

For the ActivityLogSearchModel the view rendered would be:

```
@model ActivityLogSearchModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
```

For the ErrorLogSearchModel the view rendered would be:

```
@model ErrorLogSearchModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ErrorMessage)
```

What I want to do is that, on the click of a button the inheriting model is submitted via AJAX to an action method in my controller which receives the base class as parameter.

```
public ActionResult Search(LogSearchModel logSearchModel){
    var activityLogModel = logSearchModel as ActivityLogSearchModel;
    if(activityLogModel != null){ /*do something*/ };
    var errorLogModel = logSearchModel as ErrorLogSearchModel;
    if(errorLogModel != null){ /*do something*/ };
}
```

I have tested this approach, but when casting the result is always null. So, I attempted to create two action methods, one which receives an ActivityLogSearchModel and one that receives an ErrorLogSearchModel as parameters. However, when submitting my form I am not able to retrieve the properties of the inherited class. The following code is my AJAX call for the submit event triggered from the Activity partial view

```
var combinedSearchCriteria = combineObjects(logSearchModel, activitySearchModel);

 function combineObjects(generalSearch, activitySearch) {
        $.extend(generalSearch, activitySearch);
        return generalSearch;
    }

$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SearchActivity", "Log")",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ logSearchModel: combinedSearchCriteria }),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#extraSearchFields').html(data);
            }
        });
```

When submitting this ajax call, only the base class model properties are mapped to the parameter in the action method, and the inheriting class properties are set to null.

Is there any other approach I can follow to submit an inheriting class into an action method with partial views involved?

Comment: When you post back to `public ActionResult Search(LogSearchModel logSearchModel) {` a new instance of `LogSearchModel ` is created and its properties are set by the `DefaultModelBinder`. You need separate methods for each type. Alternatively you can create a custom model binder that checks if properties `Message` or `ErrorMessage` are present and initialize the corresponding type.

Comment: In any case, why not just add property `string Message` to `LogSearchModel`. Since the value of `LogType` determines what type of message it is, there seems not point in the inherited classes.

Comment: Felt too lame having that answer up. Damn you Stephen! Sometimes I wish there was a "Should be an answer" flag for you.

Comment: The message property is not the only property on my inherited class, I just added it as a sample here

Comment: @LuisBecerril, If you making an ajax call to post the data, you can always adjust the url based on the selected `LogType` and post back to different methods accepting the different types. Don't know what your `combineObjects()` function is doing, but you should just be using `data: $('form').serialize();`